# Tableau connection to Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, tableau-api

I am trying to connect Tableau Desktop 10 (mac) to Spark SQL 2.1 (on centos 7 server). I am connecting via Simba ODBC driver with Authentication = Username and Username = . It doesn't give any error but I don't see the tables which are available in Hive. After searching and choosing 'default' schema, and searching for tables, I only see default (default.default) table. However, when I use beeline on the server to connect to Spark SQL, the hive tables are visible.

If I use the custom SQL feature I can query the tables and use the data, but I still have no way to list the tables in Tableau.

I am not sure if the issue is on Tableau side or Spark side. I'd greatly appreciate any help with troubleshooting this issue.

[image]

Comment: So, it turns out that I can query the hive tables using Custom SQL but the tables are not visible in the left hand bar. This probably means Tableau is not able to access the schema but it is able to access the tables. 
Has anyone found a fix for this?

Comment: I get the same problem, no solutions

Comment: @fd8s0 What version of Hive and Spark are you using. I have a feeling this issue is confined to Spark 2.0+ and/or Hive 2.0+
Another user has this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976115/hive-tables-not-visible-in-tableau

Comment: that's correct, it was Spark 2.0+ and latest Hive too (2.1?) I don't work there any more so I don't remember the minor versions, sorry

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't update, I'm pretty sure this is a bug with that version of Tableau when connecting to Spark 2.0, not sure if there's any updates fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this behaviour is following:

In spark 2.0, `show tables` output format is : 'tableName', 'isTemporary' 

and 

In Spark 2.1 `show tables` output format is 'database', 'tablename', 'isTemporary'

Now Tableau 10.2.3 or greater are able to parse the output from spark2.1, but 10.2.1 and less are unable to parse this new output format.

Comment: FWIW, in Spark v2.4.1, `show tables` is back to outputting `'tableName'` (camel case), so Tableau (2019.1.2, anyways) is back to being broken / not listing tables.