# Hive tables Not Visible in Tableau

Tags: apache-spark, tableau-api

I have created a table, **ztest7** in the default database in my hive. I am able to query it using beeline. In tableau, I can query it using a custom sql.

**However the table does NOT show when I search for it.**

[image]

Am I missing something here?

```
Tableau Desktop Version = v10.1.1  
Hive = v2.0.1  
Spark = v2.1.0
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with Tableau Desktop 10 (mac) to Hive (2.1.1) via Spark SQL 2.1 (on centos 7 server)
This is what I got from Tableau Support:

> In Tableau Desktop, the ability to connect to Spark SQL without a
>   defining a default schema is not currently built into the product.
>
> As a preliminary step, to define a default schema, configure the Spark
>   SQL hivemetastore to utilize a SchemaRDD or DataFrame. This must be
>   defined in the Hive Metastore for Tableau Desktop to be able to access
>   it. Pure schema-less Spark RDD's can not be queried by Spark SQL
>   because of the lack of a schema.  RDDs can be converted into
>   SchemaRDDs, which have additional schema metadata as Spark SQL
>   provides access to SchemaRDDs. When a SchemaRDD is created, it is only
>   available in the local namespace or context, and is unavailable to
>   external services accessing Spark through ODBC and the Spark Thrift
>   Server.  For Tableau to have access, the SchemaRDD needs to be
>   registered in a catalog that is available outside of just the local
>   context; the Hive Metastore is currently the only supported service.

I don't know how to check/implement this.

PS: I'd have posted this as a comment because I am not allowed to as I am new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: In my hive create tables script, I have first created the schemas and then created the tables. The table exists in correct path/locations and can be used in custom sql, it just won't display on the left side!

Comment: I finally gave up trying to make the native install work and switched to Hortonworks HDP using Ambari. It is very simple to install and manage, though it does need root access to the cluster nodes. In any case, Hortonworks HDP install works perfectly with Tableau. I have a feeling Cloudera and MapR distributions would also work fine.

Comment: I did the same 2 weeks back @Adarsh. Ambari is working flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

In the file labeled Table on the left side of the screen, Try selecting contains, entering part of your table name and hitting enter

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issue. In my case, I had loaded tables using HIVE but the tableau connection to the data source was made using Impala as shown in the image below.

[image: Tableau connection to Data source]

To fix the issue of not seeing the tables in tableau dropdown, try running `INVALIDATE METADATA database.table_name` in the impala interface. This fixed the problem for me.

To know why this fixes the issue, refer this [link](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_invalidate_metadata.html#:%7E:text=INVALIDATE%20METADATA%20is%20required%20when,level%20Ranger%20privileges%20are%20changed.).